# How to read data from keyboard using input() with a ( ) for input?

Tags: python

I am a beginner at programming, and now I have a problem changing the input of ( ) to the users' input.

> Given a person’s weight (in kilograms) and height (in meter), his/her BMI (Body Mass Index) is calculated based on this formula:
>
> `BMI = Weight / Height2`
>
> Write a function `compute_bmi()` that reads in that order, the user's height (in meter) and weight (in kilogram), and returns a string that shows the body type of the user:
>
> - "Under" : if the BMI is lower than 18.5 (exclusive)
> - "Normal": if the BMI is higher than 18.5 (inclusive) but lower than 25 (exclusive)
> - "Over": if the BMI is higher than 25 (inclusive) but lower than 35 (exclusive)
> - "Obese": if the BMI is higher than 35 (inclusive)
>   For example, suppose height is 1.7 (meters) and weight is 68 (kilograms), function call `compute_bmi()` will read `1.7` and `68` from the keyboard and then return string `"Normal"`.
>
> Be reminded that both height and weight should be converted to float type.
>
> Note that in this question, we read data from the keyboard using `input()`. For other questions in this assignment, data are passed to our functions as parameters (i.e. they don't use `input()`). These are two different designs.

This is my programming, I tried it on IDLE and it works. but the assignment page shows it doesn't work.

```
def check_bmi():
    mass = float(data[1])
    height = float(data[0])
    BMI = mass/height**2
  
    if BMI < 18.5:
        return 'under'
    elif 18.5 <= BMI < 25:
        return 'Normal'
    elif 25 <= BMI < 35:
        return 'Over'
    else:
        return 'Obese'
```

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note on comparisons:

```
    if BMI < 18.5:
        return 'under'
    elif 18.5 <= BMI < 25:
        return 'Normal'
    elif 25 <= BMI < 35:
        return 'Over'
    else:
        return 'Obese'
```

Consider that if the first condition isn't true, `BMI` *must* be greater than or equal to `18.5`. And if the second isn't true, `BMI` *must* be greater than or equal to `25`.

```
    if BMI < 18.5:
        return 'under'
    elif BMI < 25:
        return 'Normal'
    elif BMI < 35:
        return 'Over'
    else:
        return 'Obese'
```

You would read `height` and `weight` using `input`, but you have to convert that to `float`. Remember that BMI is weight divided by height *squared*.

```
def compute_bmi():
    height = float(input())
    weight = float(input())
    BMI = weight / height ** 2

    if BMI < 18.5:
        return 'under'
    elif BMI < 25:
        return 'Normal'
    elif BMI < 35:
        return 'Over'
    else:
        return 'Obese'
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! But why we can directly use input ( )?  how could the function divides the first data as height and the second as weight without the indication?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The `input` function returns user input. You can assign that to a variable, or you can feed it directly to another function, as has been done here.